# spring boot security login return customized error message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using `Spring Boot Security` framework for a web app.  I have an issue about the user `login`.  I want to customise the error message and send it back to the page, so that I can show the message.  What I mean customised here is, e.g. `wrong user name` or `wrong user password`.  What I'm doing is as following:

**SecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private SuccessLoginHandler successLoginHandler() {
        return new SuccessLoginHandler();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(new UserPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/img/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home","/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(successLoginHandler())
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }
}
```

**UserDetailService**

```
@Service
@Scope("singleton")
class UserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private AccountDataService accountDataService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEx user = accountDataService.mGetUserExByMobile(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("not found");
        }

        List<UserGrantedAuthority> authorities = getAuthorities(user.getMobile());
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getMobile(),
                user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    private List<UserGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String mobile) {
        List<UserGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Permission> permissionList = accountDataService.mGetPermissionList(mobile);

        for (Permission perm : permissionList) {
            authorities.add(new UserGrantedAuthority(perm.getAuthority()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    public AccountDataService getAccountDataService() {
        return accountDataService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setAccountDataService(AccountDataService accountDataService) {
        this.accountDataService = accountDataService;
    }
}
```

**UserGrantedAuthority**

```
public class UserGrantedAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

    private final String authority;

    public UserGrantedAuthority(String authority) {
        Assert.hasText(authority, "A granted authority textual representation is required");
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return this.authority;
    }

}
```

**UserPasswordEncoder**

```
public class UserPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        try {
            if (encodedPassword.equals(Helper.md5(rawPassword.toString()))) {
                //Helper.md5 is just a static method to encode the password.
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**SuccessLoginHandler**

```
@Component
class SuccessLoginHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        // TODO: logic when login success

        response.sendRedirect("/index");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have created a success handler to handle the event after user successfully login.  I think probably it's similar to create a customised failure handler and set it to `failureHandler()` in `SecurityConfig`.  I've tried as following, but I can only redirect the page, I don't know how to send some extra message at the same time.

```
public class FailureLoginHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {


        //what to do to send back some message?

        response.sendRedirect("/login?error");

    }
}
```

I'm quite new to Spring Boot, any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please, follow the [OWASP guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet#Authentication_and_Error_Messages) on user authentication and don't return messages that invite an attacker for probing and guessing user accounts and passwords

Answer (score 0):

In FailureHandler set the below URL

```
   /login?error=<Some_Error_Code>
```

Get the error code in Login Controller and set the error message based on the error code appropriately to display in UI.